# How to count how often a value is submitted to a Google sheet via Google Forms per day, and put that count in different Google Sheets workbook

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I have two Google Sheets workbooks, Workbook A and Workbook B.

Workbook A is generated from a Google form that collects email addresses submitted from users. Workbook A has two columns next to each other, one with a timestamp (formatted with date and time like this: 3/11/2019 8:16:51) and the other with the email address.

I want to count the number of days each email address has been submitted. I want to put that number in Workbook B.

So here is the formula I put in Workbook B (edited for privacy):

```
=(SUM(COUNTIF(IF(IMPORTRANGE("https://linktosheetA", "Nameoftab!A:A")=TODAY(-1)))"emailIamlookingfor.com"))
```

I was going to change the email and put that formula in a cell for each person whose response rate I wanted to count.

I have two questions:

First, that formula doesn't work at all. Can it be fixed?

Second, is there a better way, overall, to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: if the same email is submitted 2x in the same day you want to count `2` or `1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("16nnuzNRxkGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW12TYwSiuaLFQIA", 
 "Sheet1!A2:B"), "where Col2 matches 'x@mail.com'"))/2
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(UNIQUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(TO_TEXT(IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "FormResponses1!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 matches 'email@address.com'")))," "))),"\d+")))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I want to count one email submission per day. They may have multiple submissions in a day, but I just want to count one.

Comment: Here is a link to a dummy version of Workbook A (note that this dummy version is NOT connected to a Google Form, but the real version is): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lzA_L3e-GmZGOBIzI_nSQz7W3RZ2gnrAoQDGM7udFj0/edit?usp=sharing

And here is a dummy version of Workbook B: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xPae2bv2iQjw1OgpDP8X8UM6EU3l855aYW9bFsTZlNA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like I'm getting the answer "1" no matter what with that formula.

Comment: So we need to count one email submission per day and count the sum of those submissions.

So if someone has submitted information once per day for 7 days, we would need to count up to 7. It's a running total of how many times that has made a daily submission via the form.

I apparently failed to remove all the private info - will you please dummify that email address in your answers? I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: done. the formula does exactly that what you request. pls double check the ID in `IMPORTRANGE` currently it imports from your real sheet not from the dummy sheet you set up. that could be the reason why `1` is never changing

Comment: I thought I changed the link, but I will double check! Thanks again, this is PHENOMENALLY helpful. :)

Comment: It is still not working. It is returning a count of 1 for everything. I am using this formula:

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("correct-link-for-the-workbook-im-pulling-data-from", "FormResponses1!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 matches 'fakename@fakeemail.com'")," "), ,1))))

I may have caused some confusion. This formula is going to go in the "total days submitted" column, which will show for each individual how many days they have submitted their answers through the form.

Comment: pls take a look here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oil0XC1nAOMJnPz0NcYb0m0Qd4fjCMImXta_7Zw-hY8/edit#gid=519023173

Comment: I still can't get the formula to return anything other than a count of 1.

Comment: hmm... did you allow access? run this formula first: `=IMPORTRANGE("correct-link-for-the-workbook-im-pulling-data-from", "FormResponses1!A2:B")` you will get **#REF** error, then hover the mouse cursor over it and a button will appear called **Allow access** click on it and then your formula should work...

Comment: I did allow access. I'm going to create a different scoresheet and start over and see if I can get this to work.

Comment: This just still isn't working. I can't figure out why. I'm using this formula:

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("LinkorIDofthegooglesheet", "FormResponses1!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 matches 'email@addressiamlookingfor.com'")," "), ,1))))`

Comment: well, not really sure how can I help you further. the formula you are using is correct and as proven here twice - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oil0XC1nAOMJnPz0NcYb0m0Qd4fjCMImXta_7Zw-hY8/edit#gid=519023173 - its working without any flaws

Comment: I don't know. I believe you - I am not sure why it wouldn't work. Once I added it to another sheet in the workbook it worked. That is not my preferred way of doing it, but I'll accept that for now. Thanks again for all your thorough and consistent help. :)

Comment: try this variation: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(UNIQUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(TO_TEXT(IFERROR(QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("LinkorIDofthegooglesheet", "FormResponses1!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 matches 'email@addressiamlookingfor.com'")))," "))),"\d+")))))`